# EntityFrameworkCore relationship between models and on cascade delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relationship

I have these Classes :

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        nameA = string.Empty;

        ListB = new List<B>();
    }

    public string nameA { get; set; }

    public List<B> ListB { get; set; }
}


public class B
{
    public C cObject { get; set; }

    public string nameB { get; set; }

}

public class C
{
    public string nameC { get; set; }

}
```

I'm using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` to work with the Database for these models, I'm able to generate the DB and the right tables, but I'm missing two things :

1. The relationship between (A and B), and( B and C).
2. and the Ability the Add and delete objects on cascade (for example
   in my case when deleting an Object A delete the corresponding List
   of B objects with it).

Here is the Code in my Context File :

```
public class Context : DbContext
{

    #region Tables

    public DbSet<A> As{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public Context(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        //primary key's
        modelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasKey(x => x.nameA);
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>().HasKey(x => x.nameB);
        modelBuilder.Entity<C>().HasKey(x => x.nameC);


        //foreign key's 
        modelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasMany<B>(app => app.ListB);
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>().HasOne<C>(app => app.cObject);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

Comment: the modelBuilder.Entity<tEntity>() don't have a  .HasOptional()  in my case or WillCascadeOnDelete() ..i don't know what command to use in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: The question is whether the relationships are optional or required. In other words, can `B` exist without `A` or without `C`. For more info, see [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) section of the documentation.

Comment: in my Case it's required for A to have a list of B , and optional for B to have a C object ...and thank's for the link to the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code for your requirement. You have to use `A` table's PK as the foreign key in `B` and `C` tables PK as the foreign key on `B`. If you want the `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` then you have to use `Required`. Or you can do this using [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#cascade-delete-1).

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        nameA = string.Empty;
        ListB = new List<B>();
    }

    public string nameA { get; set; }
    public List<B> B{ get; set; }
}

public class B
{

    public int CForeignKey { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CForeignKey")]
    public C C { get; set; }

    public string nameB { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AForeignKey { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AForeignKey")]
    public A A {get; set;}

}

public class C
{
    public string nameC { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent API:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
            .HasOne(p => p.A)
            .WithMany(b => b.B)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
```